# Origami Axiom 4 is Redundant? (Huzita–Hatori)

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, axioms, origami

I have some question regarding Huzita–Hatori axioms.

**Axiom 4** states that given a line and a point, we can make a fold passing through the point perpendicular to the line.

**Axiom 5** states that given two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ and a line $l_1$, we can make a fold that places $p_1$ onto $l_1$ and passes through $p_2$ (as shown below).

[image: Axiom 5]

Now I will show that axiom 4 can be constructed with axiom 5. Let $l$ be a line and $p$ be a point. Pick any point $q$ on the line $l$. Now by axiom 5, we can make a fold that places $q$ to $q'$ (where $q'$ lies on $l$) such that fold passes through $p$ (see below).

[image: Axiom 4 using axiom 5]

This will construct a perpendicular from $p$ to the line $l$ making axiom 4 redundant.

Is my argument correct or is there some flaw in it?

Comment: Axiom 5 might just give you the fold passing through $q$ and $p$ (i. e. the one given by Axiom 1). This will almost certainly not be perpendicular to $l$.

Comment: That does make sense. Maybe axiom 4 exists to avoid ambiguity.